# Salesforce - passing a string from one class to another! - APEX

Tags: salesforce, parameter-passing, apex-code

**Hello**, 
     I have a issue at the moment and I am not able to solve it.

**Problem**: I have 2 classes at the moment for example class A and Class B. Inside class A I have a for loop running on Accounts.

```
Class A{
    for(Account t: listAccounts){
         String abc = t.Name;
         String URL = 'http://testURL.com/test?q1='+t.id+'&q2='+t.Name.......till q50';
    }
}
```

So everytime this for loop runs on an account, it generates a new URL. I want a way to pass this URL from the for loop to another class which displays it on a VF page. So, the class B is the controller of the VF page.

The URL is going to be more than 500 characters long so its not possible to pass it as a custom setting and retrive it on the other controller.

```
Class B{
       public String getURL(){
         //Somehow fetch that URL everytime the loop runs 
         return URL;
       }
}
```

Now, the VF page will call this controller class B to retrieve the URL and display it as a output link.

**What I have tried**: I have tried to use getters and setters but it did not work. Why? because the VF page strictly calls a getURL() method with no parameters.

I also tried to save it in a custom setting but since the length is so long it would not be possible!

**Please help. Any kinds of helps will be much appreciated!**

Comment: If you opens your visualforce page it calls controller B, the controller B calls controller A to get the URL. It that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help but the only way out I could find is saving it on a custom object which has a look up on Account and then doing a SOQL to get it in the Class B.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try global static variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static method on Class A to return the URL for a given `Account` object.

Then Class B can look up the Id of the current account on the Visualforce page:

```
Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

And pass that Id to the static method of Class A to get the URL for that Account.

This works for a Visualforce page that shows the detail for an Account, but wouldn't work for a list of Accounts.